# How to work with a freshly imported vector?

Tags: grass-gis

I have a text file with points coordinates:

```
$ cat ControlPoints.txt 
-10153967|8326376
-10621243|8176811
-11122894|8184333
-9657869|8379692
-10014696|8056719
-10014696|8056719
```

I import them with `v.in.ascii`:

```
> v.in.ascii input=ControlPoints.txt output=control_points
Scanning input for column types...
Number of columns: 2
Number of rows: 18
Importing points...
 100%
Building topology for vector map <control_points@PERMANENT>...
Registering primitives...
```

So far so good, but if I try to use this vector as target for some operation I get an error:

```
> v.what.rast map=control_points raster=soc_masked column=soc
ERROR: Database connection not defined for layer 1
```

A database connection must be set manually for this new vector, [as alluded in the Wiki](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Vector_Layers). However, creating a connection to the default database fails:

```
> v.db.connect map=control_points table=control_points -o
ERROR: Table <control_points> does not exist in database
       <$GISDBASE/$LOCATION_NAME/$MAPSET/sqlite/sqlite.db>
```

I am unable to use this vector. What should be the correct workflow to import a fully functional vector? Do I need to create a database table manually?

Comment: Typically, after importing X-Y locations with `v.in.ascii`, you would run `v.db.addtable` specifying the column names and types in the '`columns=` parameter

Comment: Alternatively, use a 3rd column to get in attributes. See https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.in.ascii.html#example-4---point-format-mode---csv-table